# GetLogicalDriveStrings NT/SetupAPI alternative

Tags: windows, kernel, nt

I have to get a list of logical drives. I know I can use GetLogicalDriveStrings but I'm wondering if there's a NT API alternative I can use? Or even SetupAPI?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to correctly handle logical drives that aren't necessarily assigned letters, you'd use `FindFirstVolume`/`FindNextVolume` and `GetVolumePathNamesForVolumeNameW`.

MSDN has a sample named [Displaying Volume Paths](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/cc542456(v=vs.85).aspx)

If trying to access this information from kernel mode, try the Mount Point Manager (`\Device\MountPointManager`).